# How to prevent page reload while bookmarking it?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf.js

I am making a book library site using laravel. I am trying to add bookmark functionality. I have tried doing something like that on click of bookmark button, page no is being send to database and it is working. Issue is that on return from controller page is getting reload causing book to back on page no 1. Is there is any way that data sends to database without page reload??
I know a bit that ajax do this, but I am using JavaScript in my application and I tried to deploy ajax with it but no luck. 
I am showing up my code. Any good suggestions would be highly appreciated.

My javascript function:

```
function bookmark()
{
    book = '<?php echo $book->id ?>';

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "save_bookmark",
            data: {b_id:book, p_no:count},

            success: function(response){
                 console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                 console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

count is defined up in script.

My route:

```
Route::post("save_bookmark/{b_id}/{p_no}",'BookmarkController@create')->name('save_bookmark');
```

My controller:

```
public function create($b_id, $p_no)
{
    $b=new bookmark;           
    $b->u_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $b->book_id=$b_id;
    $b->p_no=$p_no;
    $b->save();  
    return response()->json([
        'status'     => 'success']);   
}
```

My html:

```
 <li><a id="bookmark" onclick="bookmark()" >Bookmark</a></li>
```

**Note:** There is a navbar of which bookmark is a part. There is no form submission.

Comment: I'm just gonna take a guess and say that you have a `<form>` element and inside that form element you have a button. If that button is not `type="button"` it will submit the form by default. Does your form have an action? Hence the page reload when you're trying to do an ajax call. I believe the form is submitting when you click the button to save the page number.

Comment: What is calling "bookmark"? And your route appears to show that the params are meant to be in the URL, but (unless I'm mistaken) that's not what your JS is doing.

Comment: do you have a `bookmark` function for every book? `book = '<?php echo $book->id ?>';` seems to be wrong (most probably). Can you share more of your frontend code? If you have a button you could give it a data attribute (`<button data-book="<?= $book->id ?>">Bookmark</button>` and your javascript can access this data prop then.

Answer (score 0):

you need add event to function and add preventDefault

```
<button class="..." onclick="bookmark(event)">action</button>
```

in js:

```
function bookmark(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    book = '<?php echo $book->id ?>';

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "save_bookmark",
            data: {b_id:book, p_no:count},

            success: function(response){
                 console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                 console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

in controller you ned use it:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
...
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $b=new bookmark();           
    $b->u_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $b->book_id=$request->get('b_id');
    $b->p_no=$request->get('p_no');
    $b->save();  
    return response()->json([
        'status'     => 'success']);   
}
```

in route use it:

```
Route::post("save_bookmark/",'BookmarkController@create')->name('save_bookmark');
```

Comment: Hae mate!! Thanks for replying. I deployed what you said and I am getting error : Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: sorry , i have error. you need use it

<button class="..." onclick="bookmark(event)">action</button>

just change this to event

Comment: It worked.. Can u have look at my controller function as data is not getting save in database

Comment: where you get count var for it ?  data: {b_id:book, p_no:count}
i don't see it in your js code

Comment: These are defined up in script. They are getting right values. I have checked them

Comment: i edit my answer, try use it. if it not work for you, then i need see full your code for help

Comment: I have created gist of my code. Kindly have a look. https://gist.github.com/Maha-Waqar/1975baf780335ee5a96d152b872c1580

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194542/discussion-between---and-maha-waqar).

Comment: Is your Bookmark model spelled like bookmark or like Bookmark?
Because in your BookController you're using the constructor as `new bookmark()`. Laravel might send you an error so I would check the response payload to see what's in.
Also, your AJAX request is a GET request whereas in your routes you defined it as a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this: use javascript to get the book id

$("#btnClick").change(function(e){

        //console.log(e);
        var book_id= e.target.value;

        //$token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        //ajax
        $.get('save_bookmark?book_id='+book_id, function(data){
        //console.log(data);

        })
    });

//route
Route::get("/save_bookmark",'BookmarkController@create');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming your `bookmark()` JavaScript function is being called on a form submit, I guess you only have to prevent the form to be submitted. So your HTML code would looks like this:

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); bookmark();">
```

Obviously, if you're handling events in your **script.js** it would rather looks like this:

**HTML**

```html
<form id="bookmark" method="POST">
  <input type="number" hidden="hidden" name="bookmark-input" id="bookmark-input" value="{{ $book->id }}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Bookmark this page" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function bookmark(book_id, count) {  
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "save_bookmark",
    data: {
      b_id: book_id,
      p_no: count
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}

let form = document.getElementById('bookmark');
let count = 1;

console.log(form); //I check I got the right element

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  console.log('Form is being submitted');
  let book_id = document.getElementById("bookmark-input").value;
  bookmark(book_id, count);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also I would recommend you to avoid as much as possible to insert PHP code inside your JavaScript code. It makes it hard to maintain, it does not make it clear to read neither... It can seems to be a good idea at first but it is not. You should always find a better alternative :)

For example you also have the `data-*` to pass data to an HTML tag via PHP ([more about data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)).